# Aws bounce error, Temporary mail addresses like mailinator.com or etc. causes bounce or not?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, email-bounces

My application sends alert and emails from using aws mail services but today aws send me a notification that says bounce rate over %20 it should be below %10.

But app doesn't have any unverified mail addresses except mailinator.com(which are Disposable mails). Should i block that mail domains?

Comment: Bounce rate is not what happens with your email address it is happening with the emails that you are sending and that emails are not getting delivered to those emails

Comment: I know that but users register my system with any email domain, i don't controll them all. Some of them are using disposable mails so my application sends email to them. Thats why aws warned me. Should i block that disposable domains while register process?

Comment: i don't think mailinator is the issue here. You are free to use any email_address@mailinator.com  address and it should get delivered, which can be accessed by anyone who know what the address is. Those email-addresses are not auto-deleted just the mails that arrive in those addresses are deleted.

Comment: Are you [handling bounces and complaints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/best-practices-bounces-complaints.html) and removing those addresses, as SES **requires** you to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blocking email domains is tough, because neither whitelisting nor blacklisting are an option.

By whitelisting certain domains, you disallow people with email domains that are unknown to you (but might be perfectly valid), while by blacklisting you have to update the list of blacklisted domains on a daily basis, since new "10 minute email" domains emerge every day.

Please note that temporary email addresses are invented for a way of saying: *"Hey, I don't trust this website with my own email adrress"*, so you're most probably not going to trick users that are willing to hide their real address since they've got a valid reason to do so.

Can't you adopt and implement something like [OpenID](http://openid.net/get-an-openid/what-is-openid/)?

Comment: Good advices. Thank you for informations. I have to think about adding open id to register and logins later.